# Title and back button not showing in navigation bar item (iOS 7)

Tags: uikit, ios7, uinavigationbar

I just started coding for iOS 7 and can't make the title and back button appear in the Navigation item. What can cause this and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show some code of what you are trying to do, how your view controllers are set up, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your ViewController is embed in NavigationController. (Choose your ViewController from Storyboard, then go to Editor menu from Xcode and Embed in -> NavigationController)

Drag and drop the Navigation Item into your ViewController, and now you can enter the title of your ViewController and name for you back button.